# To find Wronskian of a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_{1}=\phi(x)$ and $y_{2}=\psi(x)$ be solutions of the ODE

$$y''-2xy'+(sinx^2)y=0$$

such that $\phi(0)=1,\phi'(0)=1$ and $\psi(0)=1,\psi'(0)=2$. Then the value of the Wronskian $W(\phi,\psi)$ at $x=1$ is

1. $0$
2. $1$
3. $e$
4. $e^2$

The Wronskian of a set of solutions for a second order ODE has a formula of the form: $W[\phi,\psi](x) = Ce^{f(x)}$, where $C$ is a constant and $f(x)$ is a function. I know that at any point $x_0$

\begin{alignat*}{2}
W(x_{0}) &= \left|
\begin{matrix}
\phi(x_{0}) & \psi(x_{0}) \\
\phi^{\prime}(x_{0}) & \psi^{\prime}(x_{0}) \\
\end{matrix}
\right|
&= \phi(x_{0})\psi^{\prime}(x_{0}) - \psi(x_{0})\phi^{\prime}(x_{0})
\end{alignat*}

but I am unable to find  $C$ and $f$. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: find the ODE that $W$ satisfies by writing $W'(x)$ in terms of $W(x)$, and using the fact that both $\phi$ and $\psi$ are solutions of the original ODE.

Comment: nice................+1

Answer (score 0):

The Wronskian of your equation satisfies the DE $$W'(x)=2x\,W (x) . $$ You also know that $W (0)=1$. So $$W (x)=e^{x^2}.$$